# How to generate noise using specific variance

Tags: matlab, noise

In the matlab function `awgn()` that is used to add noise to a signal, is there a way specify the variance?

In general, I would have simply done   `noisevec = sqrt(2)*randn(length(X),1);` creates a noise vector of variance 2. Then the noisy observations are

```
Y = X+noisevec
```

But, I would like to apply awgn() and then check if the variance of noise is indeed as specified by the user. How to do that?

```
         % add noise to produce
         % an SNR of 10dB, use:
         X = sin(0:pi/8:6*pi);
         Y = awgn(X,10,'measured');
```

UPDATE : Based on the solution, the output should be same when generating noise with specific variance using the awgn() given in the answer/ solution provided and when using without awgn(). Is something wrong in my understanding? Here is how I checked.

```
x =  rand(1,10); $generating source input
snr =10;
variance = 0.1;
%This procedure is  based on the answer
y1 = awgn(x, snr, 'measured');
y1 = x + (y1 - x) * sqrt(variance / var(y1 - x));

%This is the traditional way, without using awgn()

 y2 = x+sqrt(variance)*randn(1,10);
```

y1 is not equal to y2. I wonder why?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to verify that the variance of awgn() is really what it says it is?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I want to know if we can use awgn() to generate a noisy signal with a specific noise variance.

Comment: Would `var(Y-X)` work? I think that would give you the variance of what `awgn()` applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awgn` does not generate a noise with a specific variance. But if you have to generate a noise with a specific variance, you may consider defining your own noise generator which could be simply scaling the noise up or down to the desired level:

```
function y = AddMyNoise(x, variance)
    y = awgn(x, 10, 'measured');
    y = x + (y - x) * sqrt(variance / var(y - x));
end
```

UPDATE: Note that this method of forcing the output to have a specific variance **could be dangerous:** It will give strange outputs if x has few elements. In the limit of x being a scalar, this approach will add a fixed value of +-sqrt(variance) to x. No white noise anymore. But if you have more than a few data points, you will get a reasonably white noise.

Comment: This is quite a weird function - snr serves no purpose here.  Why not just use a scaled version of randn?

Comment: You are right about `snr`, @OliverCharlesworth. I edited my answer accordingly. But there is a big difference between the output of `randn` and what is known as _noise._ In signal processing, white noise is a random signal with a constant power spectral density. It means *the spectrum of the noise matters.* Take a look at [the definition of white noise.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)

Comment: After the most recent edit I think this answer makes sense.

Comment: @erfan - I understand that - but `randn` will give you WGN (its samples are Gaussian-distributed, and independent).  I suspect if you dig into the implementation of `awgn` you'll find that it just calls `randn`.

Comment: You are right again @OliverCharlesworth, I mistook the concept. But I keep the answer as it is, since `awgn` also generates complex noise if necessary, while one needs to do it manually when using `randn`.

Comment: @erfan: Sorry to sound noisy but I double checked your approach by creating noisy signal from your approach and by using awgn(). But the output is different. Could you please see the updated Question?

Comment: @SKM See the update in my answer. That is the only difference I would expect. Besides that, indeed the outputs are always different, since they are stochastic anyway.